# How to change calendar language in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, widget

After searching, I dont find the appropriate way to resolve following problem.

After activating the calendar widget, it dont find the way to change its language (Instead of english months have french months and also for the "S S F T W T M").
Which file in worpdress folder to deal with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess most of the stuff that you find still in english is the dates: names of months and days. Initially I thought that the "non-translating" problem had something to do with using the date() function instead of a different one that could be localized. However the solution has been "simpler". The process:

1) Edit the "the-events-calendar.class.php" file located in the root directory of the plugin.

2) Search for the "public function monthNames( $short = false )" and translate the values that the $months array take, for example:

$months = array( 'Jan'  => __('Ene', $this->pluginDomain),

$months = array( 'January' => __('Enero', $this->pluginDomain),

Change only the value 'Ene', 'Enero' not the key of the array that should continue being: 'Jan', 'January'...

Save the file an upload to the corresponding root directory of the plugin on your WordPress installation.

Regarding some other Words that have not been translated in the .po and .mo files, I recommend reading this post of WordPress documentation. http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Cheers!